# How to import from a text into an array excluding certain characters from the text file

Tags: java, arrays, text, import

I have been struggling with this homework for a couple of days. I was able to import another text file containing just last names perfectly fine but for the boys names there is a number, a period and a space before each name.

There is also a tab after each name. For the girls names for the most part they are split simply by a space but there is a tab randomly inbetween some names. The names for boys and girls aren't easily split by new lines and are  mainly on long lines.

This is what the names on the boy text file look like

(Tabs dont appear so I'm putting a "\t" where there should be a tab)

1. Liam \t 2. Noah  \t 3. William    \t 4. James    \t 5. Logan \t 6. Benjamin  \t 7. Mason \t 8. Elijah \t

This is what the names on the girls text file look like

(Tabs dont appear so I'm putting a "\t" where there should be a tab)

Emma Olivia \t Ava Isabella Sophia  \t Mia  Charlotte   \t Amelia   \t Evelyn   Abigail Harper  Emily   \t Elizabeth    \t Avery

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

  FileReader fr = new 
      FileReader("C:\\Users\\siegh\\Desktop\\lastNames0219.txt");
  FileReader fr1 = new 
  FileReader("C:\\Users\\siegh\\Desktop\\boyNames0219.txt");
  FileReader fr2 = new 
  FileReader("C:\\Users\\siegh\\Desktop\\girlsNames0219.txt");
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
  BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(fr1);
  BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(fr2);

  String line = "";

  /*String[] tokens = str.split("\t")
   *String[] tokens = str.split("\t");
   *String[] tokens = str.split("\n");
   *String[] tokens = str.split("[\t, \n]");

    */
  ArrayList<Names> lastNames = new ArrayList<>();
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
      Names n = new Names();
      n.lastName = tokens[0];
      lastNames.add(n);
  }

  ArrayList<Names> boysNames = new ArrayList<>();
  while ((line = br1.read()-*) != null) {
      String[] tokens = line.split("[,\t,.]+");
      Names bn = new Names();
      bn.firstNameBoy = tokens[0];
      boysNames.add(bn);
  }

  ArrayList<Names> girlsNames = new ArrayList<>();
  while ((line = br2.readLine()) != null) {
      String[] tokens = line.split("[., ]");
      Names gn = new Names();
      gn.firstNameGirl = tokens[0];
      girlsNames.add(gn);
  }

  StringBuilder javaText = new StringBuilder();
  javaText.append("String[] firstNameBoy = { ");
  for (Names bn: boysNames) {
      javaText.append('\"' + bn.firstNameBoy.replaceFirst("", "") + 
   "\", ");
  }

  javaText.append("};");

  StringBuilder javaText1 = new StringBuilder();
  javaText1.append("String[] firstNameGirl = { ");
  for (Names gn: girlsNames) {
      javaText1.append('\"' + gn.firstNameGirl.replaceFirst("", "") + 
   "\", ");
  }

  javaText1.append("};");

  StringBuilder javaText2 = new StringBuilder();
  javaText2.append("String[] lastName = {");
  for (Names n: lastNames) {
      javaText2.append('\"' + n.lastName.replaceFirst(" ", "") + "\", 
  ");
  }
  javaText2.append("};");

  System.out.println(javaText);
       //      System.out.println();
      //      System.out.println();
      //      System.out.println(javaText1);
     //      System.out.println(); 
       //      System.out.println();
       //      System.out.println(javaText2);
         }
            }
```

The end goal is to have the an array of 1200 names. 600 boy names and 600 girl names with randomly generated last names attached to each.

This is what I end up getting when I run my code.

String[] firstNameBoy = { "1", };

Comment: For boys split input lines by \t, then split each of the string by space.

Comment: I am getting plenty of compilation error with your code.

Comment: Alternately, `String.split()` takes regex, not literal characters, so you can give a set of characters to use (`.split("[ \t]+")`) or even just use the regex special character that matches any whitespace (`.split("\\s+")`).